# How do I use Java's Semaphore in a LIFO way?

Tags: java, semaphore

I would like to know if there is a way to use the Java Semaphore class in a LIFO way.

I set the fairness flag as true so it would honor the order in which the threads try to acquire the semaphore. In default, the class works in a FIFO way -- the first one that tried to acquire the semaphore will get it first.

I am asking this question since it makes much sense to have it built in the class since it seems that it would be pretty easy to implement if it were implemented in the class (perhaps by simply changing the data structure that keeps the acquisition requests from a queue to a stack). However, so far, I have not been able to find a documentation nor any article that explain how I can use the class that way.

My question is: is there a way to use the Semaphore class in a LIFO way, or should I build my own semaphore that does that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your understanding is partially correct. By default its not FIFO. if you set fairness to true then its FIFO

Comment: Thanks almas shaikh for your comment. I have already set the fairness flag to true, which made my Semaphore work in the FIFO way. I wonder if there would be any way to change it to work in a LIFO way.

Comment: You probably need to use a `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: The basis for a Semaphore (and other concurrent classes) is the [AbstractQueuedSynchronizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html) and in the API it says you can use "your own custom Queue classes". You can create a [LifoQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#asLifoQueue%28java.util.Deque%29), but I do not know how you would use/extend the `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` to make it use your own custom Queue class.

Comment: I'd be interested to understand the use case for this. In general this is a recipe for deadlocks because the first in thread is likely to be starved of the semaphore and, therefore, less likely to release other semaphores it holds. Could you comment on why you need this - not doubting there is a reason I'm just curious as to what it is.

Comment: @sprinter, in my program, the number of threads requesting for the resource I'm protecting fluctuates much. It is ok to starve the earlier threads requested for the resource, in an exchange for serving the later threads, and those starved threads will be served at some point during an idle time. Also, since there is only one semaphore, I believe it will not cause any deadlock. Thank you all for your comments!

Comment: Thank you, @hfontanez. That was the answer I was looking for!